# Function pointer pointing to a function that takes a function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How do I declare a function pointer that points to a function taking the same function pointer as the argument?

I've tried the following without success:

```
typedef void (*fnptr)(void (*)());

void func(fnptr)
{
    /* ... */
}

void func2(fnptr)
{
    /* ... */
}

void main()
{
    fnptr fn = &func;
    func2(fn);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Im not sure if you can,it would be like trying to templatize something with itself, you just end up with a recursive declaration

Comment: I rather think it cannot be done.

Comment: How about just using a generic declaration and an explicit cast?

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to do that ?

Comment: A function cannot easily take itself as a parameter, can it? What would be the use of that?

Comment: @BoPersson: There are a lot of applications involving higher order functions (e.g. combinators) and implementations of finite automata that require this kind of recursive definition, as well as any programs which use explicit-continuation style to "manually" implement lightweight threading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I very much doubt it, but you can get the needed recursion by introducing a struct.

```
struct Rec;

typedef void (*RecFun)(const Rec&);

struct Rec {
    RecFun fun;
};
```

Example of use:

```
#include <iostream>

void nothing(const Rec& rec) {}
Rec recNothing = { nothing };

void f(const Rec& rec)
{
    std::cout << "f\n";
    rec.fun(recNothing);
}
Rec recF = { f };

void g(const Rec& rec)
{
    std::cout << "g\n";
    rec.fun(recNothing);
}
Rec recG = { g };

int main()
{
    recF.fun(recG);
}
```

**Update:** As per the suggestions of Chris, Vitus, and Johannes, here are some convenient implicit conversions (as in Herb Sutter's [GotW #57](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm)):

```
struct Rec;

typedef void (*RecFun)(const Rec&);

struct Rec {
    RecFun fun;
    Rec(RecFun fun) : fun(fun) {}
    operator RecFun() const { return fun; }
};
```

Comment: You could even override `operator()` so that it looks and behaves like a function (a functor), if you prefer that syntax

Comment: You were close to solving it. By abusing the way the question was posed, you *can* actually solve it. The question asked for a function that *takes* the same function as *argument*. That means, if your struct has a converting constructor that converts from the function, then you actually have a function that takes itself as an *argument*. He did *not* ask for a function that has its own type as a parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just typedef both. A function pointer is a parameter just like any other type:

```
typedef (* InnerFunctionPtr)(void);
typedef (* OuterFunctionPtr)(InnerFunctionPtr);
```

**Edit:** Folks have pointed out you mean both to be the same type. In that case, it's not possible, as the type would be recursive. It's impossible to create a complete type specification (the type of the function's parameter is never completely specified, ergo...)

Comment: I think the OP means an argument of the same type.

Comment: The 'OuterFunctionPtr' would have to take an 'OuterFunctionPtr' as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, it cannot be done.  It would be nice if you could use `typename` to forward declare a typedef; something like:

```
typename fnptr;
typedef (*fnptr)(fnptr);
```

but that does not work, because `typename` is restricted to a few specific template uses

Answer (score 0):

it is possible in this way:

```
typedef void (*fnptr)(void (*)());

fnptr fn1,fn2;
void func(fn1)
{
/* ... */
}

void func2(fn2)
{
/* ... */
}
void main()
{
fnptr fn = &func;
func2(fn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also defeat the type system by pretending that the function takes some other function pointer type, and then casting it when you pass something to the function and inside the function to get the original type back.

Not recommended obviously, but just putting it out there.

```
typedef void (*fnptr)(void (*)());

void func(void (*x)())
{
    fnptr f = (fnptr)x;
    /* ... */
}

void func2(void (*x)())
{
    fnptr f = (fnptr)x;
    /* ... */
}

void main()
{
    fnptr fn = &func;
    func2((void (*)())fn);
}
```