# Function returning pointer to itself?

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to write a function that returns a pointer to itself?

If no, suggest some other solution to make the following syntax work:

```
some_type f ()
{
    static int cnt = 1;
    std::cout << cnt++ << std::endl;
}
int main ()
{
    f()()()...(); // n calls
}
```

This must print all the numbers from 1 to `n`.

Comment: Aren't recursive functions a simpler option to your question ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: the question was about to make the syntax work, not about how to print n numbers using the same function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function pointer pointing to a function that takes a function pointer...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128344/function-pointer-pointing-to-a-function-that-takes-a-function-pointer)

Comment: Basically a duplicate of said question, as it addresses the same problem: recursively referencing the function (type) in said function (signature).

Comment: @San: I don't think the question is idiotic (and I think you could have chosen a better word anyway to express the same idea). It's a curiosity question. And if one is curious to know some dirty language corners, it doesn't mean he wants to use them in production code

Comment: @San: No one said it should... just another question for aptitude

Comment: @San, I find this a very interesting question, taking me back to my grad-school days in computer science. Consider the identity function `I := λx.x` in untyped lambda calculus. It returns whatever you give it. Pass it itself (`I I`), and it returns itself, which is what this question asks for. It's impossible to define in simply typed lambda calculus because we cannot express the required types. Imagine C++: `template<class X> X I(X x){return x;}`. There's no value of `T` to make `I(I<T>)` valid. That's a problem calling for creative, constructive input. Ignore it if you wish.

Comment: Incidentally, it is quite easy to do this in C#: `class C { delegate D D(); static D M(){ return M; } }`. Or, the traditional way to do this in functional languages is to define a combinator that takes and returns its own type: `class C { delegate D D(D d); static D M(D d){ return M; } }`

Comment: @SanJacinto: If a different, hypothetical word expresses the same idea, then why bother changing the original one?!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
struct function
{
   function operator () ()
   { 
       //do stuff;
       return function();
   }
};

int main()
{
   function f;
   f()()()()()();
}
```

You can choose to return a reference to function if needed and return `*this`;

***Update:*** Of course, it is syntactically impossible for a function of type `T` to return `T*` or `T&`

***Update2:***

Of course, if you want one to preserve your syntax... that is

```
some_type f()
{
}
```

Then here's an Idea

```
struct functor;
functor f();
struct functor
{
   functor operator()()
   {
      return f();
   }
};

functor f()
{  
    return functor();
}

int main()
{
    f()()()()();
}
```

Comment: @Armen: +1. You could simply do this : `return *this;`  No need to create another functor!

Comment: Just so i understand *this resolves to teh function address if in a function & an object address if in member function ?

Comment: @Armen: Not only `return *this;`, its also better to return it as reference as : `function & operator () ()`

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, but I had included that sentence in my answer, haven't I?

Comment: @Armen: After I commented, or  probably at the same time I was commenting. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: No, that part about the reference was there from he beginning (or almost the beginnig, like after a minute, you can see the edit history) :P

Comment: @Armen: Your solution is clear to me. And it is possible do achieve that effect without replacing the original `f()` function with a functional object ?

Comment: @Armen: Hmmm... it wasn't from the beginning, that is why I didn't read it. Anyway. No issue :P

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't, because the return type has to include the return type of the function, which is recursive. You can of course return function objects or something like that which can do this.

Comment: We can. Using function objects.

Comment: @iammilind: I think that I might have explicitly mentioned that you can use function objects?

Answer (score 6):

You can use pattern of function objects:

```
struct f
{
  f& operator () ()
  {
    static int cnt = 1;
    cout<<cnt++<<endl;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Just you need to put one extra `()`. Usage:

```
f()()()(); //prints 1,2,3
```

[Here is the demo.](http://www.ideone.com/0Yx0M)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, just look the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void * (*func)();

void * test()
{
    printf("this is test\n");
    return (void *)&test;
}

int main()
{
    (*(func)test())();
}
```

The result is :

```
user@linux:~/work/test> gcc test_func.cc -o test          
user@linux:~/work/test> ./test
this is test
this is test
```

Comment: Very very ugly solution. If you want to call it third time, if you've to do this : `((*func)(*(func)test())())();`

Comment: It is not guaranteed by the standard that a function pointer can safely be converted to void *

Comment: It's just a way to show that it can do that, although it's not a good implementation.

Comment: Not only not guaranteed by the standard, but forbidden by the standard.  This code should not even compile if the compiler is invoked in compliant mode.

Comment: The function object implementation

Comment: @James Kanze: I think we fixed that. The old wording essentially disallowed `dlsym`/`GetProcAddress` which were considered reasonable cases. IIRC it was the first go at "conditionally supported behavior"

Comment: @MSalters I don't know what there was to fix.  Posix offers stronger guarantees, and the Posix standard shows how to handle the conversion legally, given the stronger guarantees.  For the rest of the word, the fact that data pointers and function pointers may have different sizes and representations is a distinct possibility, that portable code has to take into account.

Comment: @James Kanze: POSIX offered incompatible guarantees. In ISO C++98, it was an error, diagnostic required; in POSIX it was well-defined behavior. Under the "conditionally supported behavior" rule, it's either implementation-defined behavior or an error (diagnostic required). I.e. POSIX implementations can refer to POSIX standard; implementations where it's impossible must still give an error.

Comment: @MSalters The version of the Posix standard I have on line guarantees that all pointers will have the same size and representation, and suggests `*(void**)(&fptr) = dlsym...`, with `fptr` declared as a pointer to function, for the conversion; they make it quite clear that using something like `(int (*)())dlsym` requires a diagnostic from the compiler.  (But of course, no one actually writes it that way, and all Unix compilers do support the direct conversion, so "conditionally supported" is about the closest to actual practice.  But it does hurt portability.)