# function pointed to by function pointer returning function pointer to other function of same type

Tags: c++, function-pointers, state-machine

What a title

Hi all,

i want to implement a state-machine which is managed by a looped call of a fp. In the functions (after data management), the pointer should be pointed to a different function of the same type, depending on sensor data. This is the return-type of the function, which then gets called again over the now updated fp. This allows me to catch the transitions every time a state changes. The functions mostly deal with an LCD-display.

i tried the following:

```
static void* (*pNowF)(LiquidCrystal_I2C);
static void* (*pNextF)(LiquidCrystal_I2C);
pNowF = defaultState;

while(true){

    pNextF = pNowF(LCD);
    pNowF = pNextF;

}
```

with

```
void* defaultState(LiquidCrystal_I2C MainLCD){
    
    //...data management

    //while in defaultState, only 3 transitions can happen:
    
    if(myFlags->press1){ //determined by sensor 1
        pNextF = state1;
        return pNextF;
    }

    if(myFlags->press2){ //determined by sensor 2
        pNextF = state2;
        return pNextF;
    }

    while(myFlags->idle){
        //stay in this state
    }
}
```

i get that the return type of these state-functions doesnt correspond with what the fp expects, but how do i declare the return type of a function to be a fp to its own type?

Comment: any reason why you are not using std::function? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a function cannot return a function pointer (it's explicitly disallowed by the standard)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes not correct. You cannot return a function, but returning a function pointer is fine

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes https://godbolt.org/z/nYx3M4

Comment: a function whose return type is the same of the function itself is recursive. With a level of indirect you can surely do it, but the return type is part of the functions type, hence they cannot be the same

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505461/function-returning-pointer-to-itself and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128344/function-pointer-pointing-to-a-function-that-takes-a-function-pointer