# Defining a typedef for a function that returns a function pointer to a function like itself

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm a bit stumped on this one.  The easiest way to think about it is a set of functions that implement states of a state machine and return the next state (please note - the FSM example is just motivational, I'm not looking for how to design a FSM).

So I'm looking for a C style typedef and a C++ 11 using definition of StateHandler (a function pointer) where the code would be something like (ignoring declarations, etc...):

```
// typdef for StateHandler
// -- and to see the new c++ 11 way --
// using StateHandler = StateHandler (*)(State *, int);  // note -- does not compile

StateHandler StateOne(State *state, int arbitraryArgs) {
    // do stuff and go to state 2
    return StateTwo;
}

StateHandler StateTwo(State *state, int arbitraryArgs) {
     // do stuff and go to state 1
    return StateOne;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The duplicates above led me to [gotw57](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/057.htm) which addresses this exact scenario for C++ at least.  The solution is tricky since it hinges on a typedef allowing a struct to be returned by value before the definition of the struct is available.This is a rare case where google completely failed me.

Comment: @user2976512, it's not very tricky for the compiler.  (Although yes, it can look strange for a human!)  A function declaration doesn't need to know very much about types.  But a function *definition* usually does.  If a function is going to return an object by value, then the function definition does need to know the size and layout of the struct, but the declaration beforehand does not.  Hence this is a pretty standard technique.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this as it would require the infinite type. You need to use function objects here.

```
struct StateOne;
struct StateTwo;

struct StateOne {
    StateTwo operator()(State* state, int arbitraryArgs) const;
};

struct StateTwo {
    StateOne operator()(State* state, int arbitraryArgs) const;
};

StateTwo StateOne::operator()(State* state, int arbitraryArgs) const {
    // do stuff
    return StateTwo();
}

StateOne StateTwo::operator()(State* state, int arbitraryArgs) const {
    // do stuff
    return StateOne();
}
```

If you want a variable that can store either of these function objects, you need type erasure. You can do this with an abstract base class that contains a pure virtual `operator()` function, and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: It seems to be pretty straightforward to get it to work, see my answer.  Unless I've misunderstood something in the question?  You can have one simple struct type which contains a function pointer.  Then define the `()` operator, thereby allowing a function to return a function-like-object to itself (or to another function of the same type.)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Heh, didn’t think of that.

Comment: I only discovered it a few weeks ago!  See the comment from @rici linking to a very relevant answer here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128344/function-pointer-pointing-to-a-function-that-takes-a-function-pointer

Answer (score 1):

Where `FuncType` is the name for the type of the function, you can't have it return `FuncType`.  But you can have it return a lightweight wrapper around the function type (`StateHandler`).  Then we can define the function call operator `operator()` so that this behaves just like a function.

```
struct StateHandler;

typedef StateHandler (*FuncType)(State *, int); //using FuncType = StateHandler (*)(State *, int);

struct StateHandler {
        FuncType m_f;
        StateHandler(FuncType f_) : m_f(f_) {}
        StateHandler operator() (State *s, int arbitraryArgs) {
                return m_f(s,arbitraryArgs);
        }
};

// declare both functions in advance, so their definitions can return each other
StateHandler StateOne(State *state, int arbitraryArgs);
StateHandler StateTwo(State *state, int arbitraryArgs);

StateHandler StateOne(State *state, int arbitraryArgs) {
    // do stuff and go to state 2
    return StateTwo;
}

StateHandler StateTwo(State *state, int arbitraryArgs) {
     // do stuff and go to state 1
    return StateTwo;
}
```